# Pandas DataFrames: How to delete rows in a dataframe based on a sequential comparison of their index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a data frame named `red_data_frame`. Each row has a unique index value spanning from `1 to 54075`. What I need to do is to iterate through each value and delete the row if it is immediately sequential. For example:

```
1
721
722
...
```

Delete `722`

```
...
1442
1443
...
```

Delete `1443` etc...

The new dataframe should remove all rows that meet this condition.

[image: Snippet of red_data_frame]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case try

```
out = df[df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1)]
```